# I am trying to test my project, but creating a user in users.yml file is returning a validation error relating to the password (using Devise & Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, yaml, minitest

EDIT: It's fixed! My issue was that I had added the line:

```
  validates :password, presence: true
```

in my User model which was causing an error (it's obsolete) because Devise already validates this in the below:

```
devise :database_authenticatable
```

---

I am trying to learn TDD and so have created a small recipe creation app using Rails and Devise. It's my first time posting so I'm sorry if I've missed anything here! I have added the following tests:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test 'valid user' do
    assert @user.valid?
  end
end
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Failure:
UserTest#test_valid_user [/Users/Hannah/Projects/recipe-app/test/models/user_test.rb:15]:
Expected false to be truthy.

rails test test/models/user_test.rb:14
```

If I add @user.save! above assert @user.valid? I receive the following:

```
Error:
UserTest#test_valid_user:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank
    test/models/user_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

My users.yml file looks like this (help found in other stack overflow answers), but I couldn't find a solution to my specific issue:

```
one:
  first_name: Jane
  last_name: Doe
  email: jane@gmail.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
```

I'm not sure what part I'm doing incorrectly here and have struggled to find a similar issue online, or the answer in any documentation.

I got around it by creating a user within my tests themselves, but I really need to fix this because I need the user test file to be able to test the recipe part of my app (recipes require a valid user id, so I need to be able to reference the users.yml file in my recipes.yml file I think).

Comment: if you don't need to use the password just try this -- encrypted_password: "password"

Answer (score 0):

You should  never actually deal with the encypted password attribute directly. Just provide cleartext passwords and let Devise do its job.

```
one:
  first_name: Jane
  last_name: Doe
  email: jane@gmail.com
  password: 'password'
  password_confirmation: 'password'
```

Your fixtures, tests and everthing else should merely use the abstractions that Devise provides like the `password=` setter and `authenticate?` so that the underlying implementation doesn't leak into your code. This prevents your code from breaking if the underlying implementation changes.

Comment: Thanks so much! However when I do this, it says there is no column called password in the users table. I can do this and it does work though: encrypted_password: password